# Argcomplete confusing scripts

Tags: python, autocomplete, arguments, ubuntu-14.04, argparse

I am trying to use argcomplete to autocomplete the possible parameters to be entered to my script "setup_warehouse_env" :

```
def env_completer(prefix, **kwargs):
    # Run the command cman env list and return the results as a list of strings
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("cman env list"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    env_list = process.stdout.readlines()
    env_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in env_list]
    print env_list
    return [v for v in env_list if v.startswith(prefix or '')]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Choose the warehouse environment')
    arg_parser.add_argument('--environment', type=str, default='',
                            help="Environment name").completer = env_completer
    argcomplete.autocomplete(arg_parser)
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()
```

The problem is that I have another script already using arg complete (a script called cman) and my script here somehow ends up having the same autocompletion than the cman script. What I want it to have however are the options that the command "cman env list" gives back (a list of strings).

I have another bash script to set my environment this way

```
eval "$(register-python-argcomplete setup_warehouse_env 2>/dev/null)"
```

And setup_warehouse_env is installed to a global binary folder so that it can be found.
I noticed that the function "env_completer" is not even called as I don't see the result of

```
print env_list
```

when I push tab for the autocomplete.